# Is Adobe Lightroom worth it for a student amatuer photographer?

Tags: lightroom, photography-basics

I am a hobbyist photographer, and I am considering buying Adobe Lightroom. Do you guys think that Lightroom is necessary for someone who shoots in RAW with the Nikon D3200? I shoot fairly often, but photography is just a hobby for me.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE. This site is slightly different than a regular forum in the sense that discussions are not really encouraged. Answers should be based on facts, not on personal opinions (generally speaking). If LR is `worth it` is purely defined by you, we can not answer the question using research or our own experience. You can try out the Lightroom trial and see if you find it worth the money.

Comment: @BartArondson Thanks for the info about this site. I will try out the trial.

Comment: As you're a student, it should be noted that there are some special edition for students and educators.  [(See here for a BH link)](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=979667&gclid=CPbT4LuvjL8CFSJo7AodQwEAxg&Q=&is=REG&A=details). If you're a university student, there may also be purchase options available directly through your university.

Comment: I would suggest reading my answer to a similar question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/43234/6284

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely recommend getting it, but you might want to wait a month or two... Usually close to the launch of the new lightroom you can find it for 60 or 70$.... If you time it right, within 30 days of the official launch you can even get adobe to upgrade you to the newest one. As mentioned in another comment, use the trial and learn how the program works... There are tons of free resources and videos to help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add:

You can get [darktable](http://www.darktable.org/) for FREE, and it does most of what you'll need for RAW editing, including some very advanced features.

So is Lightroom necessary for a hobbyist? given darktable's capabilities, I'd say the answer is a no.

Answer (score 0):

Totally worth it! The 10 dollar a month subscription price also gives you the laters Photoshop CC 2014 and any updates as they happen.  I have on this program for a few years now and it's great!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely recommend buying Adobe Lightroom, it is a lot easier to get used to than Photoshop CS6 and helps organise your photo library very well. I would either recommend you go for Lightroom or Photoshop Elements, both are great for editing to suit the amateur photographer. Furthermore all Adobe software has a strong community, with plenty of tutorials to help you as well as information around the internet.